# Ruby 1.9.2 + valums + rawfileupload = no deal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Before updating my Macbook I used Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.9 my app worked very nice.

UPD: actually the problem was different, see the answer below.

Now I have the same Rails (as it is in Gemfile) but Ruby Version is 1.9.2, and I have some problems with it. So the one of them is that I've lost the ability to upload files through valums AJAX uploader and `rawfileupload`. It seems clear, all the data is passed through:

```
{"photo"=>{
  "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd47fe5df20 
     @original_filename="appleberry.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers=nil, 
     @tempfile=#<File:blah-blah a real file, i can see it>}, 
  "album_id"=>"6", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"<is ok>=", "qqfile"=>"appleberry.jpg"
}
```

But then I get the following SQL insert:

```
INSERT INTO "photos" (
  "name", "description", 
  "created_at", "updated_at", 
  "album_id", "image_file_name", 
  "image_content_type", "image_file_size", 
  "image_updated_at", "created_by") 
VALUES (NULL, NULL, 
  '2011-10-23 19:08:18.746030', '2011-10-23 19:08:18.746030', 
  6, NULL, 
  NULL, NULL, 
  NULL, NULL)
```

It can`t be a controller, because it`s supersimple

```
@photo = Photo.new(params[:image])
@photo.album_id = params[:album_id]

if @photo.save
   ...
```

That's a nasty problem, I tried even to downgrade to `ruby 1.8.7`, since I'm using `rvm`, but I haven't got it yet. If the best way is using `1.8.7` I'll do so, but, please, tell my how =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, as I found out. In rails I had a wrong declaration of Photo.new(), I used `params[:image]` but it should have been `params[:photo]`. And that`s why I got a lot of `NULLs` in a query.

Just keep it in mind next time, saving images